# Uninitialized constant error when routing partials according to their slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to refactor a view with the following pattern:

View code:

```
<%= render @static_page.render_nested_partial %>
```

Model code:

```
def render_nested_partial
  return FormPartialResolver.new(self).resolve_path
end
```

Parent code:

```
# partial_resolver/form_partial_resolver.rb
class FormPartialResolver
  def initialize(static_page)
    @static_page = static_page
  end

  # It should return something like "FormPartialResolver::Home"
  def resolve_path
    "FormPartialResolver::#{@static_page.slug.underscore.camelize}".constantize.new(@static_page).partial_path
  end

  def partial_path
    # it should return the path "form_partials/home_wrap"
    return "form_partials/#{@static_page.slug.underscore}_wrap"
  end
end
```

Child code:

```
# partial_resolver/home.rb
module PartialResolver
  class Home < FormPartialResolver
    def initialize(static_page)
      super(static_page)
    end
  end
end
```

This produces the following error:

> Showing project/app/views/admin/static_pages/_form.html.erb where line #33 raised:
>
> uninitialized constant FormPartialResolver::Home8d0bdef24dc34f8bAb1c006feeb02845
>
> ```
> def resolve_path
>   "FormPartialResolver::#{@static_page.slug.underscore.camelize}".constantize.new(@static_page.slug).> partial_path
> end
> ```

I guess I'm not passing the right parameter.
What could I do to have just "Home"?

Comment: what's the value of `@static_page.slug`?

Comment: Already solved. 
it was 'home8d0bdef24dc34f8bAb1c006feeb02845' because I was trying to define a module wrong.. 
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code...

```
module PartialResolver
  class Home < FormPartialResolver
```

defines a module `PartialResolver`, containing a class `Home`.  You can reference it using `PartialResolver::Home`, **not** `FormPartialResolver::Home`.

Your code attempts to use `FormPartialResolver::Home`, which is not defined anywhere we can see here. Your `Home` class **inherits** from `FormPartialResolver`, but that has nothing to do with how you reference the class, rather, you use the containing modules and classes (`PartialResolver` in this case) and the scope resolution operator, `::`.

You can fix this by updating your `resolve_path` to return the correct string representing your module and class:

```
# It should return something like "PartialResolver::Home"
def resolve_path
  "PartialResolver::#{@static_page.slug.underscore.camelize}"...
end
```

Comment: It worked! And thank you very much for the explanation!!